# Finding Milestones that are changing in term of specific milestone

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I need a query to find all the milestones if I make any change for milestonetotalmonth using java spring features where milestoneno is 1 and that is related to milestonestartedfrom [table iamge:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/359Jg.png)  Is it possible ?

I tried in java to fetch the milestoneno and store in a List of Object array

Comment: As per question guidelines, pls do not post images

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far and what issue or error you are getting with your query. Then only others can help you.

Comment: Sir, I have not tried any efficient thing that can lead me. I have written a query select milestoneno  from table_1 where milestonestartedfrom = 1(suppose) so that I am getting 2 and 3 . now for that 2 and 3 I wanted same query until the data are related to each other ,I don't know it's sound inapproprite or not that is something I am looking